# Django - how to tell if user was redirected to the page by @login_required?

Tags: django, redirect, python-decorators, login-required

I want to use the

```
@login_required
```

decorator for a view called

```
allUsers_page
```

, which is used when you go to the url

```
r'^users/allUsers$'
```

In my settings.py, I have

```
LOGIN_URL='/login'
```

so when a user goes to the

```
allUser_page
```

view (when he goes to the url

```
users/allUsers
```

, if the user is not signed into his account, it will redirect him to the login page. Now, in the login page, is there a way for me to find out if the user just went to the login page directly or if he was redirected to the login page by the

```
@login_required
```

decorator? Basically, I want my login page to be something like

```
{% if the user was redirected to this page by @login_required %}
    <p>Hi, you must log in in order to view the page you were trying to view.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome! Please sign in.</p>
<!-- Here is where the log in form is -->
```

NOTE: I am using the generic login view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user user was redirected from another page, django will provide the `next` query string parameter, so that the user can be redirected back after signing in.

Add this to your settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

then, in the template, check if this parameter exists or not.

```
{% if 'next' in request.GET %}
```

Not tested, though.

See [Auth docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users)

Comment: You will need to add `request` to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` list in order to provide `request` to the templates.

Comment: perfect, it worked. Thanks. It basically worked. I just needed to add 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' to the 'TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS' along with what you said and it worked.

Comment: Even worse, in my old example, we have overwritten all default context processors. The correct answer is a bit longer :) Thx for the comment...